# Creating functional links on a single PHP page by using .htaccess and RewriteRule with multiple variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use a RewriteRule to clean up my URL, i need the rewrite to allow multiple different $_GET values, but they need to sometimes be empty, without causing an error.

- `www.example.com/egypt/cairo/`
- `www.example.com/egypt/cairo/almaadi/`
- `www.example.com/egypt/cairo/almaadi/rent/`

Code:

```
RewriteRule ^egyp/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ egypt.php?id=$1&id1=$2&id3=$3
```

Comment: What problem are you having with the rule you've posted? You don't _need_ to use just one rule. You should be more restrictive with the regex. `.*` matches literally anything, including slashes. Only match what is valid.

Comment: 1) `egyp` is not the same as `egypt`. 2) Why not just catch everything after `egpyt/` into one query parameter and split it on `/` in your PHP... `$ids = explode('/', $_GET['id'])`